# How do you create a dynamic filter on List based on firebase string?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to include a dynamic filter using string from firestore. The UI will show tiles based on a selection on filter(s)

[image]

I have have query to fetch Firebase documents below

```
getFoods(FoodNotifier foodNotifier) async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('Foods')
      .orderBy('create at', descending: true)
      .getDocuments();

  List<Food> _foodList = [];
```

Here below these are the string I have setup in firestore.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Food {
  String id;
  String name;
  String category;
  String newcategory;
  String image;
  List subIngredients = [];
  Timestamp createdAt;
  Timestamp updatedAt;

  static var data;

  Food();

  Food.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    name = data['name'];
    category = data['category'];
    newcategory = data['newcategory'];
    image = data['image'];
    subIngredients = data['subIngredients'];
    createdAt = data['create at'];
    updatedAt = data['updatedAt'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'category': category,
      'newcategory': newcategory,
      'image': image,
      'subIngredients': subIngredients,
      'create at': createdAt,
      'updatedAt': updatedAt,
    };
  }
```

Comment: thanks,  your advise makes complete sense,just a quick question, how do connect food.category etc.. connecting, I am creating variables to the query?

Comment: getFoods(FoodNotifier foodNotifier) async {
var query =  Firestore.instance
      .collection('Foods')
      .orderBy('create at', descending: true);

var food = Food;

var category = '';


if (food.category != "") {
    query = query.where("category", isEqualTo: food.category);
}
var name;
if (food.name != "") {
    query = query.where("name", isEqualTo: food.name);
}
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await query.getDocuments();

List<Food> _foodList = [];

snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
  Food food = Food.fromMap(document.data);

  _foodList.add(food);
  });

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment. If you're having a hard time making the advice in my question work, I recommend updating your quesiton with what you tried, or posting a new question (if it's a new problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to build a query out of multiple conditions. Every time you call `where` it returns a new `Query` object. So by calling that for each condition, you can build up the query.

```
var query =  Firestore.instance
      .collection('Foods')
      .orderBy('create at', descending: true);
if (food.category != "") {
    query = query.where("category", isEqualTo: food.category);
}
if (food.name != "") {
    query = query.where("name", isEqualTo: food.name);
}
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await query.getDocuments();
...
```